# Insert query, string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-insert

Why does this keep happening? The first 2 data types are `Int`. The 'Games' is `DateTime`. The last is `VarChar`. Why is it not executing successfully

```
CREATE TABLE JaretSchedule
(
    FieldID int Primary,
    TeamID int Foreign,
    Games DateTime,
    TeamsPlaying varChar
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[JaretsSchedule]
        ([FieldID]
        ,[TeamID]
        ,[Games]
        ,[TeamsPlaying])
    VALUES('1', '1', '2012-01-20 12:00:00', 'Roadrunners v.s. Cheetahs');
```

Error Message: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Comment: `VALUES (1, 1, ` -- don't enclose numbers in single quotes.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the `CREATE` statement for the table, as **text**, **not** as screenshot. And while you at it also include the query and the error message as **text** and **not** as an image. Remove the image.

Comment: What is the size of the `varchar` column? Possibly, the value that you want to insert is too big to fit in it.

Comment: This seems to have a bit of a normalization issue. Why is there a varchar column with the name of the two teams? You already have the TeamID in one column. Why not add a second column like OpponentID. Then you have the ID for each team and you would query the name when you pull the data. Not only is that simpler, you have the ability to change the name of a team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default length of `varchar` when used as a column data type is 1.

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-size string data
>
> . . .
>
> When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

[char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

So you need so set a max length for the column.  EG

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists JaretsSchedule
go

create table JaretsSchedule
(
   FieldId int,
   TeamID int,
   Games datetime,
   TeamsPlaying varchar(255)
)

go
insert into JaretsSchedule(FieldId,TeamID,Games,TeamsPlaying)
values (1,1,'2012-01-20 10:00:00','Roadrunnersv.s.Cheetahs')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because ,you have exceeded the max size of field,

```
ALTER TABLE JaretsSchedule ALTER COLUMN TeamsPlaying nvarchar(1000);
```